# 2D array of struct in c

Tags: c, matrix

I am trying to make a 2D array there every spot in will contain three integers in C.
this is my code:

```
typedef struct node
{
    int path;
    int y;
    int z;
}node;

typedef struct graph
{
    node *matrix[10][10];   
}graph;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    graph*map=malloc(sizeof(graph));
    map->matrix[0][0]->path=1;
    printf("%d",map->matrix[0][0]->path);
}
```

when I run it I get an seglation fault, is it something I missing?

Comment: In a quick glance I can see that node has no member named path, the code won't compile, you should post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[using the definitions before the OP edit]

the code you give cannot compile because *matrix* is defined as

> ```
> node *matrix[10][10];
> ```

non compatible with

> ```
> matrix[0].path
> ```

but having

> ```
> graph*map=malloc(sizeof(graph));
> ```

does not allocate the memory for the elements in *matrix*, so doing something like that (to be compatible with your definitions) :

> ```
> map->matrix[0][0]->x=1;
> ```

you dereference a non initialized pointer with an undefined behavior (your segmentation fault)

you also need to initialize the pointers in *matrix*, a priori allocating memory like (at least) :

```
map->matrix[0][0] = malloc(sizeof(node));
```

or do not use pointers having :

```
node matrix[10][10];
```

Comment: thank you I saw now that have posted wrong code but your tips helped me anyway

Comment: @xguekl24 you welcome, please take care next times you publish code to give the right one ;-)